# Configuring TheHive with TLS

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to configure TheHive to support TLS (https instead of http). It has a configuration file read by Play Framework.
Any ideas how?

https://docs.thehive-project.org/thehive/operations/https/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to configure HTTPS in Play Framework, I'd recommend having a look to the official documentation: [Configuring HTTPS - Providing configuration](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ConfiguringHttps#Providing-configuration).